# Converting a column of Unix time stamp to UTC format

Tags: python, unix-timestamp

I have to convert the col5 of Unix time stamp to UTC format (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss) with python script and create a new col6 for UTC format in the following data.

## Data:

col1   col2    col3    col4      col5

0       0       0       1       1231006505
1       1       0       1       1231469665
2       2       0       1       1231469744
3       3       0       1       1231470173
4       4       0       1       1231470988
5       5       0       1       1231471428
6       6       0       1       1231471789
7       7       0       1       1231472369
8       8       0       1       1231472743
9       9       0       1       1231473279
10      10      0       1       1231473952
11      11      0       1       1231474360
12      12      0       1       1231474888
13      13      0       1       1231475020
14      14      0       1       1231475589
15      15      0       1       1231562746
16      16      0       1       1231562758
17      17      0       1       1231563791
18      18      0       1       1231564334
19      19      0       1       1231564974
20      20      0       1       1231565995
21      21      0       1       1231566553
22      22      0       1       1231567467

I am new to python .Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated .

Thanks in advance .

Regards

Rubz

Comment: Please don't add your solution to your question. Post it as an answer instead.

Comment: done! @RobertColumbia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the datetime module to format the data into any date format you desire.

```
from datetime import datetime

unix_timestamp = float("1231006505")
utc_timestamp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix_timestamp)
print(utc_timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

You can look at all the different format options for strftime() [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Good luck!

Comment: @Rubz If it worked please mark this as the correct answer (if it is sufficient for the answer), and up vote it if it deserved kudos. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

solved with following code:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
d={}
fin = open("unix.txt","r")
fout = open("unixtoutc.txt",'w')
foutWriter=csv.writer(fout)
for line in fin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    f = line.split("\t")
    k=f[0]
    unix_timestamp = float(f[0])
    utc_timestamp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix_timestamp)
    df=(utc_timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    print(df)
    foutWriter.writerow([f[0]+"\t"+df])
fin.close()
fout.close()
```